# Change some default words for a specific language code in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to change some words that are poorly translated into Persian. I've searched this issue but I couldn't find any article about it. I've only changed the LANGUAGE_CODE, and I don't want a website for both languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a **locale** directory in your project or app.

Then add the directory to [**`LOCALE_PATHS`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths)([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths)) in `settings.py`:

```
import os
  
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
PROJECT_APP_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PROJECT_APP = os.path.basename(PROJECT_APP_PATH)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_APP_PATH)

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]
```

Then run command `makemessages`:

```
python manage.py makemessages -l fa
```

It creates (or updates) a message file in the directory **locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES**. In the de example, the file will be **locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/django.po**.

Now you can edit the translations for whichever strings you like.

For example: open **locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/django.po** and add desired [strings](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/django.po):

```
msgid "No fields changed."
msgstr "فیلدی تغییر نیافته است." # Override it to desired translation

msgid "None"
msgstr "هیچ" # Override it to desired translation
```

After you create your message file – and each time you make changes to it – you’ll need to compile it into a more efficient form, for use by **gettext**. Do this with the utility:

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

This command runs over all available **.po** files and creates **.mo** files, which are binary files optimized for use by **gettext**.

For more info look at [Localization: how to create language files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. there is one problem, and it's not working for django allauth

Comment: @KuroshGhanizadeh, I use too django-allauth in my projects. It works well! What string do you try to translate?

Comment: @KuroshGhanizadeh, you can also override django-allauth templates for project. Just include : `templates/account/signup.html` or `templates/socialaccount/signup.html`

Comment: Yes, I think I should override templates